# Load local file through HTML page inside stage webview

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, stagewebview

I have to show local image file in html through stagewebview.
When I load url of html  in flex application, text content displyaed correctly, but it doesn't show a images for that. Any way I can load local file through html in stage web view?

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves copying all your necessary files (html, images, css) to a storage directory, and then call your html in there. The URLs to images and CSS will be relative to that directory.

This code shows how to copy the contents of an entire directory called `html` into that storage directory, and then load `test.html` into your StageWebView object.

```
        var source:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("html/") ;
        var destination:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
        source.copyTo(destination, true);
        var initialURL = new File(destination.resolvePath("test.html").nativePath).url;
        webView.loadURL( initialURL );
```

Be aware that you will be responsible for cleaning up that directory though.

Comment: Im using this method with great success on my android test devices (need to address the valid 'cleanup' issue though) but can't get the method to work on iOS.  The air app (specifically, the stagewebview within the app) doesn't load the html at all and doesn't generate any error.  is the file://  something that works on ios?  seems it should just work same because its inside AIR, but I guess the ios filesystem could work differently?  any experience with this method on ios?

Answer (score 0):

You can load a local HTML file using the File Class. So it would be something like this:

```
var _locaWebFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(pathToHTMLContent);     
var _webview:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
_stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
_webview.stage = _stage;
_webview.loadURL(_localWebFile.url);
_webview.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, loadData);

function loadData(e:Event):void
{
  _webview.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, _stage.stageWidth, _stage.stageHeight);
}
```

Also, you might have to make sure your paths to your images are correct.